# Accessing/Mounting Vue3/Vite App Outside of non-Library Bundle

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I am building a Vue3/Vite application and using the default `vite.config.ts`. The application will be `mount()`ed in several .NET Razor templates possibly on differently tagged elements. I also need to inject some configuration data from the template into the application.

I had originally built the application as a library bundled as ESM that exports my app and the plugins it uses and then calling `createApp` in the template. I don't think it scales well and, since the application uses Pinia, [there are other issues](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/2205). The template:

```
<script type="importmap">
    { 
        "imports": {
           "@@vue/devtools-api": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@vue/devtools-api/lib/esm/index.js",
            "pinia": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pinia/dist/pinia.esm-browser.js",
            "MyApp": "/scripts/myapp.js",
            "vue-demi": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-demi/lib/v3/index.mjs",
            "vue": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.esm-browser.prod.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue';
    import { MyApp, store, ChartPlugin} from 'MyApp';
    createApp(MyApp, {
        projectId: '@Model.Project_ID.ToString()',
    }).use(store).use(ChartPlugin).mount('#my-app');
</script>
```

Ideally I'd like my template to look something like this:

```
<script ??? src="/scripts/myapp.js"></script>
<script>
    MyApp.provide({'projectId': '@Model.Project_ID.ToString()'}).mount('#my-app')
</script>
```

So I am looking for a way to get access to the result of calling `createApp` with all of it's plugins within my app/library and delaying the mount and configuration to within the server side template.

I could put my application on the `window`:

```
...
const MyApp = createApp(MyComponent).use(store).use(ChartPlugin)
;(window as any).MyApp = MyApp  // I would make this cast go away
```

Then the template code becomes:

```
<script type="module" src="/scripts/myapp.js"></script>
<script>
    window.MyApp.provide({'projectId': '@Model.Project_ID.ToString()'}).mount('#my-app')
</script>
```

Is there another/better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a function that create the app (don't create it immediately):

```
export function createAndMountApp(elem, props = {}){
   // do creation and mounting here
   return createApp(() => h(Component, props)).....mount(elem);
}
```

Comment: Excellent idea. I'm missing how to configure vite(rollup?) to export a function in a way that I can call it without compiling as an ESM library.

Comment: I was able to work around Pinia's ESM module by defining process.env.NODE_ENV via https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973 so I used the Vite's `build.lib.formats` set to `['es']`  and `<script type="module"` to include the library in my server template.

Comment: @saschwarz you can prohibit dynamic imports and compile it into 1 js file. assign the createAndMountApp to `window` and use it as a global function. This could allow to avoid ESM hopefully